# How do I right justify string in Python 3 not counting the string itself?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Just started learning python. And it looks to me that **rjust()** method is counting string that I'm trying to justify in justifying length.

Let me clarify a little bit, the book I'm using to study python had this type of small program:

```
order = "First\nSecond\nThird"
print("The order is: ", order)
```

Whose output is:

```
The order is: First  
Second  
Third
```

And I thought what could I change to make output as (**desired output**),

```
The order is: First   
              Second   
              Third
```

Well *there may be very easy way to solve this* but bear in mind I just started learning python. I tried formatting to no avail. After learning about list I came up with this solution,

```
order = "First\nSecond\nThird"

listed_order = order.split("\n")
length_of_list = len(listed_order)

print_line = "The order is: "
length = len(print_line)

print(print_line + listed_order[0])
for i in range(1, length_of_list):
    print(listed_order[i].rjust(length))
```

But the output is,

```
The order is: First
        Second
         Third
```

That means rjust() method is counting Second and Third to make justified length of 14, while I wanted them to start from 14. Second has 8 spaces in front of it to make justified length of 14, while Third has 9 spaces.

So, *what can I do to get my desired output?* If there is another way to solve this let me know.

Comment: If there is anything that I could do to improve my question please let me know.

Comment: You actually want to **left** justify your strings at a given position

Comment: @schwobaseggl Sir left justifying gives first output maybe I misunderstood your comment.

Comment: Your method nearly works (also not the simplest), you should just use `length = len(print_line + listed_order[0])` as this is the line size you want.

Comment: @RamchandraGiri That's why I said "at a given position". Look at the words you want to align: Are they aligned on their left or on their right?

Comment: @ColinPitrat Can't do that cause Second has different length then Third.

Comment: Oh my bad, I thought you wanted them aligned on the right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you describe is *left*-justified, but with an additional offset (also known as *indentation*).

Instead of

```
print(listed_order[i].rjust(length))
```

simply do

```
print(' ' * length + listed_order[i])
```

If there is nothing to the right of `listed_order[i]`, you don't need to use `ljust` either.

You might want to take a look at [`textwrap.indent`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.indent), which lets you indent whole blocks of text without splitting the lines manually.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to do such things: `length_of_list = len(listed_order)`. You can run your loop without checking length of the list:

```
for i in listed_order:
    print(i.rjust(length))
```

EDIT:
As pointed in the comments, this would also print first element which we want to skip. You can do it by telling python to process from second element by adding `[1:]`, which means `from element of index 1 (which is second after index 0) untill end)`, so:

```
for i in listed_order[1:]:
    print(i.ljust(length))
```

Now to the core.

What you need is the number of whitespaces. You can get it by running this:

```
number_of_whitespaces = len("The order is: ")
```

And then print it out before each line:

```
print(' ' * number_of_whitespaces, end='')
```

Full solution here:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

order = "First\nSecond\nThird"
print("The order is: ", order)

orders = order.split()
whitespaces = len('The order is: ')

print('The order is: {}'.format(orders[0]))
for o in orders[1:]:
    print(' ' * whitespaces, end='')
    print(o)
```

EDIT2: Added missing colon, Changed rjust to ljust
EDIT3: Added full solution

Comment: `for i in listed_order` would go through all items in the list, but the first one must be excluded.

Comment: @gonczor First of all that for statement is missing colon and secondly am I missing something cause this is not giving expected output.

Comment: I have added the colon. And this was not meant to be antire answear, I've just described a few mechanisms you could find useful. What particularily is not working?

Comment: Sir you need to change rjust to ljust to give expected output otherwise everything is good. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. I've also uploaded my full solution for this task. Just in case.